# Box creation in CSS

Tags: css

I have an unordered list as a menu and the current item has a class `active`. I want the the active item to have a little box below it like in the image attached. How would I do this using just CSS? If there is no (good) answer I will go old-school and create an image as a `background-image`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing can be done using a pseudo-element and positioning it relative to the element you're decorating: http://jsfiddle.net/fC7gn/

```
.box {
  position: relative;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your CSS:

```
a:hover{border-bottom:10px solid red;}
```

You can add the border-bottom style to any element. I attach it to the a tag so it spans the entire width of the content it contains.

[Here's an example fiddle (don't mind the extra fluff)](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/42SJ7/)